# How to fetch HTTP headers in perl when using CGI

Tags: perl, apache, http, http-headers, cgi

I'm using Perl/CGI/Apache and want to fetch the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header. How do I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Except for a few headers that are handled specially, CGI stores the value of `Header-Name:` in the environment variable `HTTP_HEADER_NAME`.  So, `X-Forwarded-For` (if present in the request) should be found in `$ENV{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}`.

Comment: @cjm, thank you so much. Is there any rfc or protocol or standard defines, web server passes http header to cgi process in environment variables way with prefix HTTP_?

Comment: @hylepo, [RFC 3875](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3875#section-4.1.18)

Answer (score 5):

CGI has a method for accessing HTTP request header fields, called "http", so you can say:

```
my $q = CGI->new()
print $q->http('X-Forwarded-For');
```

This works regardless whether you're running as a CGI, in fastcgi, mod_perl, etc...