# How to get the real client ip using the clearsilver library

Tags: c, apache, ip

I use clearsilver library to write CGI. And before my Apache, I use Haproxy. I can output the real user ip in the apache log using:

> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\"" common

But I nearly test everything, for example: `HTTP.XForwardedFor`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and so on to get the real ip from hdf, but none of them seems right. How can I get it? From which key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")`? Judging by [cgi.c](http://code.google.com/p/clearsilver/source/browse/trunk/cgi/cgi.c), clearsilver doesn't copy the X-Forwarded-For header, but you should still be able to pluck it out of the environment, where [apache put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949276/how-to-fetch-http-headers-in-perl-when-using-cgi).