# How to read all HTTP headers in Python CGI script?

Tags: python, http-headers, cgi

I have a python CGI script that receives a POST request containing a specific HTTP header. How do you read and parse the headers received? I am not using `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` or `HTTPServer`. I receive the body of the post with `sys.stdin.read()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to get a custom request header's value in an apache CGI script with python. The solution is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949493/810448).

Apache's mod_cgi will set environment variables for each HTTP request header received, the variables set in this manner will all have an `HTTP_` prefix, so for example `x-client-version: 1.2.3` will be available as variable `HTTP_X_CLIENT_VERSION`.

So, to read the above custom header just call `os.environ["HTTP_X_CLIENT_VERSION"]`.

The below script will print all `HTTP_*` headers and values:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print "Cache-Control: no-cache"
print

print "<html><body>"
for headername, headervalue in os.environ.iteritems():
    if headername.startswith("HTTP_"):
        print "<p>{0} = {1}</p>".format(headername, headervalue)


print "</html></body>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [cgi module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cgi.html) included with Python's standard library. It appears to have a [cgi.parse_header(string)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_header) function that you might find to be helpful in trying to get the headers.

Comment: cgi.parse_header('X-GitHub-Event') doesn't return the header. It doesn't return any header I have tried.

Comment: @AlecFenichel I believe its purpose is to parse the headers after you have gotten them.

Comment: Yes. But how do you get them?

Comment: This does nothing. You can't parse a header if you haven't even gotten them.